# Data Storage on Mobile App

Tags: html, mobile

Am creating a recipes mobile app. I would like the recipes to sit on the app as opposed to downloading from the internet each time user wants to access. This means I would like the recipes in the app accessible even when app is offline. How best can I store this data (recipes) on the app? The app is HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript.

Comment: Is it an app or a website for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTML5's `localStorage` for that. You can easily use this in this way:

```
localStorage.setItem("data", "This data is stored");
```

And retrieve it:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("data");
```

---

As you are trying to store multiple objects into the `localStorage` you should `stringify` them first. For example:

```
var recipes = [{"name":"Recipe 1"},{"name":"Recipe 2"}];
localStorage.setItem("recipes", JSON.stringify(recipes));
```

When you retrieve the data:

```
var recipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipes"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to either use the html5 application cache functionality to store your recipe pages 'offline' or, if you're going down a database route, make use of the localStorage functionality found in all modern browsers.

The [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info) resource will get you started:

- [Let’s take this offline](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)
- [Introducing HTML5 storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#localstorage)